# transition-property for cross-browser compatibility

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have the following code of `CSS3` for regular browsers and those with `-webkit-` suport.

But, what value should I really set for the following property:

```
-webkit-transition-property: ????;
```

Because a value like `box-shadow` is `-webkit-box-shadow` for `-webkit-` related usages, and then, for the above `property`, should I use `box-shadow` or `-webkit-box-shadow`?

Comment: you means I have to use: -webkit-transitio-property: -webkit-box-shadow instead of transition-property: box-shadow ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a transition of a property which also uses vendor prefixes itself, you need to add them.

**Example CSS:**

```
.my-class {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 1s;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-box-shadow 1s;
        -ms-transition:     -ms-box-shadow 1s;
         -o-transition:      -o-box-shadow 1s;
            transition:         box-shadow 1s;
}
```

With unprefixed properties it works like this:

```
.other-class {
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
       -moz-transition: color 1s;
        -ms-transition: color 1s;
         -o-transition: color 1s;
            transition: color 1s;
}
```

**Browser support:**

- [CSS3 transition](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)
- [CSS3 box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the corresponding vendor-prefixed property.

```
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-box-shadow;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-box-shadow; /*For older versions of Firefox only*/
transition-property: box-shadow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```
div {
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 2s;

    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-property: width;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

is the same as (using shorthand version):

```
div {
            transition: width 1s linear 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s linear 2s; /* Safari */
}
```

Here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions you can find when you need prefixes for transitions. There is a nice example here http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XEWhk/1/ from another similar question that helps a lot.